# How to compare MailingAddress of a Contact

Tags: apex, contact, address

There is a requirement to detect whether two contacts have the same `mailingaddress`.

Rather than iterating over all the mailing address components (Street, State, PostalCode etc) is  there any other way to check if two Addresses are equal?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_system_Address.htm

Comment: What is harrm in direct comparison like. Contact cd = [Select MailingAddress  from contact limit 1];
Contact cc = [Select MailingAddress  from contact where Id!=: cd.Id limit 1];
if(cc.MailingAddress  == cd.MailingAddress ){
    system.debug(true);
}

Comment: Have you tried a comparison?  Please [edit] your post to include the results.